# Add a column with distribution plot of every variable in a summary table

Tags: r

Is there a nice way to add a column with the distribution plot of every variable?

For example here:

```
library(vtable)
st(iris)
```

Not necessary to use this package. Open to suggestions

Comment: This seems very complicated to do, why not show the summary stats *in* the distribution plots themselves? :)

Comment: What do you mean how?

Comment: Try `library(summarytools);view(dfSummary(iris))`

Comment: Also, the `skim()`-function from package `skimr` could be an option if plotting histograms is sufficient.

Comment: why both missing the median statistic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I am aware that this might be much easier to do with `ggplot`, I am always eager to see whether I can achieve a similar result with **base R** plotting tools. I will make use of the `iris` data in this example.

We first need to identify which columns of our `data.frame` are numeric.

```
# returns logical which is TRUE if column p is numeric
numeric_cols <- c(rep(NA, ncol(iris)))
for(p in seq_len(ncol(iris))) {
  numeric_cols[p] <- inherits(iris[, p], 'numeric')
}
```

Then, we may select some arbitrary colours for densities. Here, I picked three colours which correspond to the number of levels of `iris$Species`.

```
my_cols <- c('blue4', 'darkorange', '#00b0a4')
adj_col <- \(x) adjustcolor(x, alpha.f = 0.2)
my_transp_cols <- c(
  adj_col('blue4'), adj_col('darkorange'), adj_col('#00b0a4')
)
```

Now we need to plot the densities. The function that is given below (i.e. `plot_densities`) has an option to either provide marginal densities or densities conditional on some factor variable. If you would like to obtain the densities conditional on some factor variable, simply set `include_factor` to `TRUE` and pass the factor variable of interest to the `factor` argument.

```
plot_densities <- \(DF, columns, include_factor = FALSE, factor) {
  name_vars <- names(DF)
  DF <- DF[complete.cases(DF[name_vars]), ]
  ## setting up plotting device
  layout(matrix(seq_len(4L), ncol = 4L))
  ## only use the TRUEs indicating numeric columns
  n_cols <- length(columns[columns])
  ## if densities are to be shown per factor level
  if (include_factor) {
    par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 8) + 0.1, xpd = TRUE)
    lvls <- unique(levels(DF[[factor]]))
    for (i in seq_len(n_cols)) {
      ## preallocation
      max_y <- max_x <- min_x <- rep(NA, length(unique(levels(DF[[factor]]))))
      means <- SDs <- rep(NA, length(unique(levels(DF[[factor]]))))
      no_of_levels <- length(lvls)
      for (j in seq_len(no_of_levels)) {
        ## only proceed with this loop if column i is numeric else next
        if (columns[i]) {
          ## subset consisting values of column i for factor level j
          sub <- subset(DF, DF[[factor]] %in% lvls[j])[, i]
          ## make sure that the densities of column i per factor level j
          ## are depicted in the same panel
          if (j == 1) {
            ## limits for the x and y axes per panel for column i
            for (k in seq_len(no_of_levels)) {
              sub_k <- subset(DF, DF[[factor]] %in% lvls[k])[, i]
              x <- density(sub_k)$x
              y <- density(sub_k)$y
              min_x[k] <- min(x)
              max_x[k] <- max(x)
              max_y[k] <- max(y)
            }
            ## mean and SD for column i per factor level j
            r <- \(x) format(round(x, 1L), nsmall = 1L)
            for (kk in seq_len(no_of_levels)) {
              sub_kk <- subset(DF, DF[[factor]] %in% lvls[kk])[, i]
              means[kk] <- r(mean(sub_kk, na.rm = TRUE))
              SDs[kk] <- r(sd(sub_kk, na.rm = TRUE))
            }
            x_lim <- c(min(min_x), max(max_x))
            y_lim <- c(0L, max(max_y))
            plot(density(sub), main = '',
                 las = 1, col = my_cols[j], xlab = '',
                 xlim = x_lim, ylim = y_lim, bty = 'n')
            title(main = names(DF)[i], xpd = TRUE, adj = 1)
            polygon(density(sub), density = -1L, col = my_transp_cols[j])
          } else {
            lines(density(sub), col = my_cols[j])
            polygon(density(sub), density = -1L, col = my_transp_cols[j])
          }
        } else next
      }
      ## add legend to the plot
      legend('topright', paste0(lvls, ': ', means, ' (', SDs, ')'),
             fill = my_transp_cols, bty = 'n',
             inset = c(-0.5, 0.1))
    }
  } else {
    ## if densities are NOT to be shown per factor level
    for (i in seq_len(n_cols)) {
      par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 8) + 0.1, xpd = TRUE)
      ## only proceed with this loop if column i is numeric else next
      if (columns[i]) {
        ## mean and SD for column i
        r <- \(x) format(round(x, 1L), nsmall = 1L)
        means <- SDs <- rep(NA, n_cols)
        for(j in seq_len(n_cols)) {
          means[j] <- r(mean(DF[, j], na.rm = TRUE))
          SDs[j] <- r(sd(DF[, j], na.rm = TRUE))
        }
        plot(density(DF[, i]),
             las = 1, main = names(DF)[i], col = my_cols[1L], xlab = '',
             bty = 'n')
        polygon(density(DF[, i]), density = -1L, col = my_transp_cols[1L])
        ## add legend to the plot
        legend('topright', paste0(names(DF)[i], ': ', means[i], ' (', SDs[i], ')'),
               fill = my_transp_cols[1L], bty = 'n',
               inset = c(-0.5, 0.1))
      } else next
    }
  }
}
```

We can save the output as .pdf file. If you would change the `layout` of the plotting device, than you would also have to play a little bit with the `width` and `height` to make it fit your specific situation.

```
# marginal densities
pdf(file = 'my_directory/my_plot.pdf', # change my_directory
    width = 13, height = 4) 
plot_densities(DF = iris, columns = numeric_cols)
dev.off()

# conditional densities
pdf(file = 'my_directory/my_plot2.pdf', # change my_directory
    width = 13, height = 4) 
plot_densities(DF = iris, columns = numeric_cols,
               include_factor = TRUE, factor = 'Species')
dev.off()
```

I usually make .pdf files of my plots and then use [this online converting tool](https://pdf2jpg.net/) to convert them to .png files.

I have shown the mean (SD) in the figure legends, but you may choose to show any statistic you like. Just change `mean(sub)` and `sd(sub)` in the function to the statistics of your interest.

**Output**

*Marginal densities*
[image]

*Conditional densities*
[image]

Note: use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)` if you use a version of R <4.1.0