# How to bootstrap dataset in R which is blocked by a factor?

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm, statistics-bootstrap

I want to perform bootstrap on this data set. Notice that the data has two factors: `replicate` and `level`, and two variables `high.density` and `low.density` that need to be regressed. I want to perform a bootstrap on this data-set but the replacements can occur only within the nested factor of replicate and level.

```
replicate level high.density low.density
    1     low    14          36
    1     low    54          31
    1     mid    82          10
    1     mid    24          NA
    2     low    12          28
    2     low    11          45
    2     mid    12          17
    2     mid    NA          24
    2      up    40          10
    2      up    NA           5
    2      up    20           2
```

For instance, in `replicate/ level`: `1/low` the `low.density` 31 and 36 can be interchanged (or `high.density` interchanged) so the head of that dataset may look like:

```
replicate level high.density low.density
    1     low    14          31
    1     low    54          36
    1     mid    82          10
    1     mid    24          NA
```

I then want to estimate the linear regression (glm) from this dataset. I would appreciate any feedback on trying to achieve this.

```
##DATA FRAME (credits: caldwellst)

    df <- structure(list(replicate = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), level = c("low", "low", "mid", "mid", "low", "low", "mid", "mid", "up", "up", "up"), high.density = c(14, 54, 82, 24, 12, 11, 12, NA, 40, NA, 20), low.density = c(36, 31, 10, 
    NA, 28, 45, 17, 24, 10, 5, 2)), class = c("spec_tbl_df","tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(replicate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), level = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character","collector")), high.density = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double","collector")), low.density = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
    
    df$replicate <- as.factor(as.numeric(df$replicate))
    df$level <- as.factor(as.character(df$level)

)
```

Comment: @Dion A plain old GLM. I tried the method you suggested but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may exploit `split` and do the sampling according to unique combinations of `replicate` and `level`. We could repeat this process `B` times.

```
df_shuffle <- function(DF) {
  my_split <- split(DF, f = ~ DF$replicate + DF$level)
  shuffle <- lapply(my_split, function(x) {
    nrX <- nrow(x)
    cbind(x[, c('replicate', 'level')],
          high.density = x[sample(seq_len(nrX), replace = TRUE), 'high.density'],
          low.density = x[sample(seq_len(nrX), replace = TRUE), 'low.density'])
  })
  DF_new <- do.call(rbind, shuffle)
  rownames(DF_new) <- NULL
  return(DF_new)
}

B <- 1000L
df_list <- replicate(B, df_shuffle(df), simplify = FALSE)
# ---------------------------------------------------
> df_list[[B]]
   replicate level high.density low.density
1          1   low           54          36
2          1   low           54          36
3          2   low           12          45
4          2   low           12          28
5          1   mid           24          10
6          1   mid           82          10
7          2   mid           NA          17
8          2   mid           12          17
9          2    up           20          10
10         2    up           40          10
11         2    up           20           5
```

Because the original data contains missing observations, we either have to multiply impute them or opt to lisewise delete them. For now, let's perform the latter option.

```
# listwise delete missing observations
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) x[complete.cases(x), ])
```

Finally, we perform a linear regression on each shuffled dataset and store the `B` coefficients in `out`.

```
row_bind <- function(x) data.frame(do.call(rbind, x))
out <- row_bind(
  lapply(df_list, function(x) lm(high.density ~ low.density, data = x)$coef)
)

## out <- row_bind(
##   lapply(df_list, function(x) glm(replicate ~ low.density, data = x,
##                            family = binomial())$coef)
## )

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
> dim(out)
[1] 1000    2
```

**Output**

```
> head(out)
  X.Intercept. low.density
1     13.74881   0.2804738
2     20.01074  -0.2095672
3     30.26643  -0.2946373
4     29.19541  -0.2752761
5     37.76273  -0.4555651
6     37.72250  -0.1548349
```

[image]

The code required to create this image can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70742396/10852113).

Comment: I am unable to run the df_shuffle bit of the code and I'm using R (on R studio, it shouldn't matter). Also, the NA's are pretty important to the dataset. I have attached the original data in the answer now.

Comment: After the new combinations has been generated I'm okay deleting the rows NAs for the individual datasets/ lists

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to run your script. I tried on an online R forum https://rdrr.io/snippets/ and it didn't work there either `Error: unexpected input in "df_shuffle <- \"` Are you sourcing the script or doing anything else?

Comment: This almost certainly is due to the fact that you have an older version of `R`, in which case you should use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`. I edited the post accordingly. Give it another try.

Comment: @Biotechgeek Did this fix the problem?

Comment: Thank you it did! I am still not sure how to get the p-value/ coefficients after the bootstrapping. Maybe that's for a separate question. This was super helpful though. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that would be a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`, `purrr`, and `tidyr`. First nest the numeric data, and then sample each of the unique combinations of `replicate` and `level` in the data. Then within those, bootstrap the unique values of the densities and then unnest for final data frame.

```r
# library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  nest(data = ends_with("density")) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 500, replace = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~summarize(.x, across(.fns = sample, size = 1)))) %>%
  unnest(cols = data)
#> # A tibble: 500 × 4
#>    replicate level high.density low.density
#>        <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1         1 low             54          31
#>  2         2 mid             12          24
#>  3         1 mid             24          10
#>  4         2 up              20           2
#>  5         2 mid             12          24
#>  6         2 mid             12          24
#>  7         1 mid             82          10
#>  8         2 up              NA           2
#>  9         1 low             14          36
#> 10         2 mid             12          17
#> # … with 490 more rows
```

#### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(replicate = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    level = c("low", "low", "mid", "mid", "low", "low", "mid", 
    "mid", "up", "up", "up"), high.density = c(14, 54, 82, 24, 
    12, 11, 12, NA, 40, NA, 20), low.density = c(36, 31, 10, 
    NA, 28, 45, 17, 24, 10, 5, 2)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(replicate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), level = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), high.density = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), low.density = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the solution but I get this error `Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `data`.
ℹ `data = map(data, ~summarize(.x, across(.fns = sample, size = 1)))`.
x argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`